# JSQMessagesViewController send button error in IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have followed used this link [Raywenlich Firebase Tutorial Real Time Chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvZM2.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvZM2.png): https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2.  for creating chat using firebase, i have followed all the procedure correctly  but when i hit send button it shows me this error,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error! required method
>   not implemented in subclass. Need to implement
>   -[JSQMessagesViewController didPressSendButton:withMessageText:senderId:senderDisplayName:date:]'

This is my code for press button to send,

```
 override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

    let itemRef = messageRef.childByAutoId() // 1

    let messageItem = [ // 2
        "senderId":Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
        "senderName": "Hamza",
        "text": text!,
        ]

    itemRef.setValue(messageItem) // 3

    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound() // 4

    finishSendingMessage() // 5
}
```

The screen is this,
[image]

Chat view Controller class

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ChatView: JSQMessagesViewController {

var ref: DatabaseReference!
var messages = [JSQMessage]()
private lazy var messageRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
private var newMessageRefHandle: DatabaseHandle?
lazy var outgoingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage = self.setupOutgoingBubble()
lazy var incomingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage = self.setupIncomingBubble()


//var senderId: NSString = ""
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    senderId = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid as NSString?)! as String!


    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero


   // observeMessages()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    return messages[indexPath.item]
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

private func setupOutgoingBubble() -> JSQMessagesBubbleImage {
    let bubbleImageFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    return bubbleImageFactory!.outgoingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleBlue())
}

private func setupIncomingBubble() -> JSQMessagesBubbleImage {
    let bubbleImageFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    return bubbleImageFactory!.incomingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleLightGray())
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    return nil
}

private func addMessage(withId id: String, name: String, text: String) {
    if let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: name, text: text) {
        messages.append(message)
    }
}

override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

    let itemRef = messageRef.childByAutoId() // 1


    let messageItem = [ // 2
        "senderId":Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
        "senderName": "Hamza",
        "text": text!,
        ]

    itemRef.setValue(messageItem) // 3

    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound() // 4

    finishSendingMessage() // 5
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? You're already overriding the required method. Try Command+Shift+K and Command+AltOption+Shift+K.

Comment: Cna u help in this or not ? @Dixit

Comment: Still not working after doing this. @Glenn

Comment: Can you post your whole view controller code?

Comment: i have edited the question check thats my whole class . @Glenn

Comment: Bro have u seen my class? @Glenn

Comment: Yes, hmmm, it's weird cause I can't see any errors in your code. Try to re-type that method and wait for the auto-completion of Xcode. Also check your pod if it's like this: `pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'`.

Comment: i have rewrite it and again check the pods if follow a video but still isn't working, i'm just fedup from this issue, stuck at it about 2 weeks. @Glenn

Comment: May I see your podfile? I don't think you're showing the whole codes of your viewController. I can't find the `cellForItemAt` datasource method. If this chat gets any longer, we can start a chat, and I'll be happy to assist you.

Comment: yup please can u come on chat or skype? @Glenn

Comment: I think you can join here in my chat on SO: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157494/room-for-glenn-and-oneeb, let's have a chat.

Comment: i have added in chat check that out . @Glenn

Comment: bro my reputation is below than 20 he is restricting  me to chat  on stackoverflow , if u can give skype id we can discuss there easily. @Glenn

Comment: I don't really use Skype, and I think it's not okay to give you my email address. The best way I can help you now is to give you this link: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/SwiftExample/SwiftExample/ChatViewController.swift That's the Swift example of the library. You can download the whole library and run their Swift Example too! Good luck!

Comment: can u come on chat room? @Glenn